# How to fit data with nonlinear partial least squares in R?

Tags: r, partial-least-squares

I am looking for a way to do nonlinear partial least squares in R or matlab. I thought kernel pls was a way to do it but it is not directly related to nonlinear pls. Do I have to calculate my own nonlinear kernel matrix and pass it to kernel pls? Any hint would be appreciated.

Update: I don't think there is any direct way to do nonlinear pls in R or matlab. But I found a package [kernlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html) that can be useful when you deal with kernels for nonlinearity. I think this can be a good start point.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the package `pls.pcr` from the CRAN?

Here is a [link](http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/pls.pcr/html/mvr.html) to the help page.

The `mvr` function has an option `method="kernelPLS"` that seem fairly easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I recognized those packages but I hoped that I can easily specify nonlinear kernels with them. But I guess I have to make my own.